# Adding an image via button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to make an app, and there would be an list view with items and its info. In the right bottom corner there would be a button, and there is my question: how to add an image and some informational text by clicking on that button?

Answer (score 0):

You really need more basics ... maybe you should start with a few simple tutorials. Whatever, for your problem you need a `RecyclerView`.